# Find an object in a list of objects by comparing with other objects attribute

Tags: python, list, object, compare

I would like to find an object in a list of objects by comparing the objects with respect to a particular attribute of the object.

```
my_list = [obj("low",1), obj("mid",5), obj("high",10)]
```

The requirement is to compare these objects with respect to the priority value(i.e. 1, 5 & 10) and return the object.

I tried to traverse the list and compare each object with the next object with respect to the priority attribute. But I get error for comparing objects in the list.

Can anyone help me out with a solution.

Comment: Can you show us the code and the exception you got?

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you are trying to achieve here, btw. Code would help.

Comment: What is especially unclear is this: "The requirement is to compare these objects with respect to the priority value(i.e. 1, 5 & 10) and return the object." What do you mean by return an object? Return an object with highest value? Return a sorted list of objects?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, title, priority):
        self.title=title
        self.priority=priority

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Obj(%r, %r)" % (self.title, self.priority)

my_list = [Obj("low", 1), Obj("mid", 5), Obj("high", 10)]
```

I'm not sure what you want to do exactly, but to get the highest and lowest priority items you can do this.

```
>>> max(my_list, key=lambda obj: obj.priority)
Out[1]: Obj('high', 10)
>>> min(my_list, key=lambda obj: obj.priority)
Out[2]: Obj('low', 1)
```

You can also filter the list, and create a new one based on an attribute of the objects.

```
>>> [obj for obj in my_list if obj.priority > 3]
Out[3]: [Obj('mid', 5), Obj('high', 10)]
```

Comment: Sorry for posting an ambiguous query. My requirement is to fetch an object from a dynamic list of object, with the highest priority value.
So it is to be achieved by comparing each object with the rest of the objects to find the right

Comment: So does the `max` line answer your question? @user964566